# Why does my UI Validation not work but HasErros is true?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have implemented INotifyDataErrorInfo. But it does not really work.
I checked the HasError with an MessageBox and it says true.
So my Errors are added. But the UI does not implement my XAML Error Template...

ErrorsViewModel:

```
    public class ErrorsViewModel : INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> _propertyErrors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        public bool HasErrors => _propertyErrors.Any();

        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            return _propertyErrors.GetValueOrDefault(propertyName, null);
        }

        public void AddError(string propertyName, string errorMessage)
        {
            if (!_propertyErrors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
            {
                _propertyErrors.Add(propertyName, new List<string>());
            }

            _propertyErrors[propertyName].Add(errorMessage);
            OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }

        public void ClearErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            if (_propertyErrors.Remove(propertyName))
            {
                OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
            }
        }

        private void OnErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

There should be an error if Kunde.Kundennr is less than 6 characters. The messagebox shows that it seems to work. But the Validation does not work.

KundeViewModel:

```
    public class KundeViewModel : ObservableObject, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        private readonly ErrorsViewModel _errorsViewModel;
        private Kunde _skunde;
        public MatchCode matchCode;
        public Kunde Skunde
        {
            get { return _skunde; }
            set
            {

                OnPropertyChanged(ref _skunde, value);

                _errorsViewModel.ClearErrors(nameof(Skunde.Kundennr));
                MessageBox.Show(Skunde.Kundennr.ToString());
                if (_skunde.Kundennr < 200000)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Servus");
                    _errorsViewModel.AddError(nameof(Skunde.Kundennr), "Kundenummer muss 6 stellig sein.");
                }
                MessageBox.Show(HasErrors.ToString());

            }
        }
        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;


        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            return _errorsViewModel.GetErrors(propertyName);
        }
        private void ErrorsViewModel_ErrorsChanged(object sender, DataErrorsChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsValid));
        }

        public bool IsValid => !HasErrors;
        public KundeViewModel()
        {
            _errorsViewModel = new ErrorsViewModel();
            _errorsViewModel.ErrorsChanged += ErrorsViewModel_ErrorsChanged;
            Skunde = new Kunde();
        }

        public bool HasErrors => _errorsViewModel.HasErrors;

    }
```

XAML:

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                <Image Source="/20.png"
                 Width="20"
                 Height="20"      
                 ToolTip="{Binding Path=ErrorContent}" Margin="5 0 5 0"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>


<TextBox  x:Name="Kundennummer" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationTemplate}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" MaxLength="6" PreviewTextInput="PreviewTextInput" FontSize="16" Margin="10 5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding KundeVM.Skunde.Kundennr, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}">
```

Comment: Does `Skunde.Kundennr` implement `RaisePropertyChanged`?

Comment: it implement INotiyPropertyChanged, it is in the ObservableObject class